# How to configure apache to serve directory for custom domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf, virtual-hosts

Currently, I have configured a domain I bought through GoDaddy to point to the elastic ip address of my personal ec2 instance. I'm having issues finding the correct solution to configure my httpd.conf such that my custom domain, example.com points to a specific subdirectory var/www/Example. Further, I want to be able to still access my other projects and sites by simply typing in the elastic ip and subdirectory.

I have tried the using a virtual host with the following configuration..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/Example/wordpress"
    ServerName fitnessfifteen.com
    ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

When I do this, I can access the correct content by going to www.example.com however, I'm unable to access my other files and projects via 11.11.111.111/OtherProjectDirectory (I get that default internal server error page). I'm completely new to this sort of stuff so many this isn't possible and I have a fundamental misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Add another virtual host to http.conf as below and restart apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/Example/wordpress/OtherProjectDirectory"
    ServerName 11.11.111.111
    ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```